# google maps for iphone with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, google-maps

I have an app built in `HTML5 + PhoneGap`,

in the application has a map of the Google-maps,

on an Android The application works fine,

I moved it to the iphone it also **runs** but it **hangs** when it should deal with `google maps`.

My link to the google map looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Do I need another link?

Comment: Did you add `maps.googleapis.com` to the whitelist, along with any other servers accessed as a result?

Comment: Where there is a white list? Where to add? I'm new in iphone ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `maps.googleapis.com` to `ExternalHosts` in `Cordova.plist`. This is a whitelist of servers that the app is allowed to access.

Check the debugging log for whitelist violation errors if the problem persists, and add any other servers as necessary.

Comment: @HodayaShalom No, just `maps.googleapis.com`. Only that. Um, I used XCode's plist editor which takes care of XML… the whitelist is an array of strings.